# EntityUtils.toString moving into IOException

Tags: java, rest, http, curl

In the following code, EntityUtils.toString is going into IOException. When I paste 'EntityUtils.toString(entity)'  on eclipse watch window, it showing me the value which is DISABLED

```
private String triggerRestApiCalls(String url){
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        getRequest.setHeader(
                new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String value = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            return value;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            log.debug(e.getCause());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug(e.getCause());
        }
        log.debug("Status Unknown");
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
```

The content value lenght is 8. The string expected is DISABLED, which is exactly of the length. The HTTP status is 200 (OK).

I used curl with same URL.

```
curl -i   -H {Accept: application/json} http://127.0.0.1:9031/test/test.html?someDetails
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D35C61744F4FB3A47B624FF3D0BEB026; Path=/mics/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 8
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 13:23:30 GMT
```

DISABLED.

Any help is appreciated ! Is there any angle to encoding ?

**FIRST EDIT**

The Stack Trace mentions this.

**`java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.`**

The code that is executed by EntityUtils.toString()

```
  public static String toString(
            final HttpEntity entity, final Charset defaultCharset) throws IOException, ParseException {
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null");
        }
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        if (instream == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (entity.getContentLength() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity too large to be buffered in memory");
            }
            int i = (int)entity.getContentLength();
            if (i < 0) {
                i = 4096;
            }
            ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
            Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
            if (charset == null) {
                charset = defaultCharset;
            }
            if (charset == null) {
                charset = HTTP.DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET;
            }
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, charset);
            CharArrayBuffer buffer = new CharArrayBuffer(i);
            char[] tmp = new char[1024];
            int l;
            while((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
    }
```

I have stepped through this and there are not errors However, it closes the stream before it returns.
But the actual value that is returned is CharArrayBuffer which is not linked to the stream. The same code works in some other java file. Strange !! I am using spring.. is there a spring angle to this ?

Comment: Stacktrace of IOException?

Comment: I have added more details. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpEntity can only be read once and it seems something else is intercepting and reading the response so that when you attempt to apply `EntityUtils.toString()` you get this exception. I can't see why this would be happening, though you did mention there could be a Spring angle so there could be a Spring interceptor applied here.

You could try

```
String value = httpClient.execute(getRequest, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

Although from what I can see this should be fairly equivalent to the above code.